# Check in of guests who didn't make the reservation

Tags: hotels, mumbai

I have booked a hotel in Mumbai (Trident Hotel, BKC) from the USA and I will be reaching Mumbai around 11 PM IST on say for example Sunday. My parents will be reaching from another city in India to Mumbai around 1 PM on the same day (Sunday).

Is it possible for my parents to check in early (around 12 or 1 PM) as I will be reaching around night time (international flight) or do they only allow the person who booked the hotel for check-in purposes?

I included three guests while booking. I can definitely give the confirmation email of booking to my parents or any authorization letter if required.

Comment: I have emailed them but I want to have other people opinion who have done this.

Comment: You need to contact the hotel and determine their policy, which may include an authorization form they provide. It's also rather likely that their check in time is later in the afternoon than 12 or 1pm, so a room may not be ready that early anyway. None of us here can tell you that particular hotel's policy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something that I have done before, although not in India. All that it took is a call to the hotel to let them know that *this guest* is expected to arrive first and that *you* will be arriving later. A print-out of the confirmation will help them check-in but is not essential, particularly if you have already entered their names on the reservation.

Ideally you have have already provided a credit-card for the reservation. Otherwise, they will ask those who come first to provide a credit-card for incidentals. Depending on the hotel, the may not insist but, if they do, you can ask them to change the credit-card on file when you arrive.

Comment: Thanks guys. That's what I was looking for. If not exact , some sort of experience in similar situation. the hotel staff told me to provide the name of the guests in advance and that was it.